# Снижение количества запросов

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю комментарии, появилась проблема, при выводе допустим 10 комментариев обычных идет 1 запрос, но если на первый комментарий есть 2 ответа, а на второй комментарий уже 7, то в в сумме получается, что идет 10 запросов к базе, а если их больше, то и запросов будет больше, как это можно оптимизировать? снизить запросы до двух

```
$q = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE url_str='$urlstr' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $lim;");

while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo '1';

$comment_id = $comment['id'];
$com = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comm2 WHERE idcom='$comment_id' ORDER BY id DESC;");

while($com2 = mysql_fetch_array($com)){
echo '1';
}

}
```

Comment: Зачем вы две таблицы под эти нужды отвели? Все комментарии в одной таблице. У каждого комментария ключ - поле, которое указывает на то, первичное ли оно или это уже ответ, подответ и т.д. и к какому ответу он относится. Вытаскиваются все комментарии, относящиеся к определенной статье или чего там у вас, а дальше строится обычное дерево по тому ключу. А двумя таблицами, вы только усложнили себе задачу.

Comment: А как построить дерево, т.е. вывести в нужное место взяв за ключ допустим ID комментария к которому относится? Следовательно если комментарий главный, то ключ можно оставлять пустым как я понимаю

Comment: @singmen, на пальцах: оставлен первый коммент, у него ключ "0", id = 10. К этому комментарию, кто-то оставил свой, у него уже id = 11 (*не важно*), а вот ключ равен 10 (*id первого коммента*). И дальше в том же духе. Вытащили всё из БД, в первом цикле (**while**) - формируем многомерный массив, где складываем каждый из комментариев в подмассив родительского. А ориентируемся **ключ_дочернего == id_родителя**. Нет родителя - значит это основное.

Comment: @Deonis, можешь помочь прописать этот многомерный массив?

Comment: @singmen, из чего я его составлять буду, из воздуха? Какой-то абстрактный пример набросать можно, а дальше самому придётся.

Comment: @Deonis, да, простой пример, а дальше уж надеюсь разберусь

Comment: @singmen, бежим по [этой ссылке][1], нажимаем Run или F9. Дальше остается только правильно вывести всю эту бяду.

   [1]:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pce8-njyw

Comment: @Deonis, не торопит вообще, подожду, буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по тому, что после моего последнего комментария воцарилась тишина, я так понял, что мой пример ясности не внёс. Сделал вам [практически полный пример](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1pfq-h34j) (*стили и прочие - от фонаря*), но надеюсь, что вопросов уже будет гораздо меньше.

Comment: @Deonis, Вчера времени не было, сегодня продолжу, как мне из базы вывести в таком виде? array('id'=>1,'parent_com_id'=>0,'name'=>'Петя','comm'=>'Драсьце','date'=>date('d-m-Y H:i:s')),

Comment: Из базы выводите так, как вы это делаете обычно. Вот в примере, вместо того массива и делаете запрос. Ниже, вместо foreach, используете цикл while. Имена полей ставите свои.

Comment: @Deonis, подскажи пожалуйста, как изменить 
<?php echo commentsString($comment['childs']); ?>
строчку, чтобы я мог использовать для под.комментов свой вид?

Comment: @singmen, Это всего лишь html-структура. Измените стили на те, которые хотите и получите свой вид.

Comment: @Deonis, я понимаю, но хочу сделать у главных комментариев, у которых 0, свой вид, его я сделал, а у остальных, у тех, которых цифры >0 другой вид

Comment: Тут особо выдумывать нечего.

    #wrapper > ul > li > .comment_content {
        // стили для первых
    }

Comment: @Deonis, с этим я знаком, в таком случае лишь css можно, а html нет. Ссылку нужно дописать в "детях"

Comment: @singmen, всё можно, но прямо сейчас у меня нет времени переделывать что-то.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот как то вот так будет более-менее нормально (возможны помарки):

```
$q = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE url_str='$urlstr' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $lim;");

$commentsID = array();
while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
  $commentsID[] = $comment['id'];
}

$com = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comm2 WHERE idcom IN ('" . implode("', '",  $commentsID) . "') ORDER BY id DESC;");

while($com2 = mysql_fetch_array($com)){
  // ...
}
```

А можно прям вообще одним запросом:

```
SELECT 
  comm2.*
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM comments WHERE url_str='$urlstr' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $lim
) subTable 
LEFT JOIN
  comm2 ON comm2.idcom = subTable.id
```

но тут возможно надо будет немножко поэксперементировать под конкретную задачу)

Comment: код вывел под.комментарии не под нужными комментариями, а под всеми, т.е. идут сначала главные комментарии, а под ними уже под.комменты.
грубо говоря, если принять твой пост, на тот, что я отвечаю сейчас как главный комментарий, а мой, как под.коммент то вот такой вид и должен выйти

Comment: Формулировка у вас конечно класс)

То что вы хотите - тут либо как сделали вы изначально (с кучей запросов). Либо потом вручную уже с помощью php сортировать, групировать и выводить комментарии там где надо.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему вы не правильно делаете выборку, т.е. саму логику выборки комментариев поста, быть может у вас не правильная структура таблицы.
Я когда делал "древовидные комментарии", как я понял это вам и нужно, делал выборку всего в один простейший запрос и уже работал с массивом данных.

Для этого было создано в таблице дополнительно поле offset в которое записывались id коментов.

К примеру:

1. Если это обычный комент, записывал просто ID коммента
2. Если это был ответ на коммент, записывал ID основного комментария и ответа на него, в таком вот формате (ID1.ID2.ID3) и так далее (где ID* это ID комментария)
3. При таком раскладе, нам нужно просто выбрать все комменты и отсортировать их по полю offset
4. Так же, это позволяет сделать отступы (древовидные комментария). Берете поле offset, создаете из него массив и считаете сколько ID в нем присутствуют. По сумме ID добавляете дополнительный стилевой класс для отступа блока слева.

Answer (score 0):

1. Либо вы сделаете один запрос который будет с вложенным подзапросом со смыслом что из вложенного вы будете получать ID новости, а из основного ответы и профит!
2. Вы сделаете 2 запроса (так проще для вас будет) - первым запросом вы получаете все комментарии к вашей новости, при этом вы будете формировать новый запрос а именно строчку `(WHERE id = $i OR)` в итоге у вас получится второй запрос и он будет типа такого: `SELECT * FROM comm2 WHERE idcom='$id_comm1' or idcom='$id_comm2' or idcom='$id_comm3`' .......

Суть донес, а там решайте сами =)

Comment: первым запросом вы получаем комментарии поста, а вторым запросом мы получаем "комментарии комментариев". ID новости получать не нужно в моем случае, я сделал вывод комментариев по УРЛу. Ведь первый цикл выводит нужное количество комментариев новости, а второй уже выводит у каждого комментария его обсуждение т.е. его комментарии, если они есть конечно, вот и получается, что у каждого комментария комментария идет свой запрос, что и пугает. Как исправить не понимаю

Comment: чтобы уменьшить до 2ух, надо сначала, прокрутит запрос с comment, и формировать второй вопрос, а потом по окончанию comment вы делаете второй запрос с формированным полностью запросом, в итоге вы получаете большой массив подкомментов который потом раскидываете по предыдущим комментам.

Comment: .

    $q = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE url_str='$urlstr' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $lim;");

     while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
     echo '1';
     }

Если вот так вот я выведу все комментарии, те, что главные, создать массив из всех под.комментариев

можно 

    $com = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comm2 ORDER BY id DESC;");

вставив это над while, а как мне вывести нужные под.комментарии в этот цикл?